# Could not include LIMIT in Axon query

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I am trying to do the following query in Axon but can't make it work. Using normal query it works -

```
SELECT user_name, email_id FROM ors_email_user WHERE email_sent=false LIMIT 5;
```

In Axon, I try to do the following -

```
$users = new Axon('ors_email_user');
$users->load(array('email_sent=:email_sent', array(':email_sent' => false)), '', 3);
while(!$users->dry()) {
   echo 'here';
}
```

It never goes inside the while loop. What is wrong with the query? Is there a way where I can see what query is actually being formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the load function only allows 3 parameters to be passed, where the third is the columns that should be ordered.

You should use the `find()` or `select()` function.  From the website:

```
find( [criteria],[order],[limit],[offset] );

select( fields,[criteria],[grouping],[order],[limit],[offset] );
```